# Which variant of amplifier to use?

Tags: amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, texas-instruments

I am making a pressure sensor circuit according to page ten of the manual [here](https://components.omron.com/us-en/ds_related_pdf/A282-E1.pdf). There are just too many types of the recommended sensor LMV324 available in the SOIC type. Can someone help me decide which sensor to use? [These](https://www.mouser.in/c/semiconductors/amplifier-ics/operational-amplifiers-op-amps/?m=Texas%20Instruments&package%20%2F%20case=SOIC-14&series=LMV324) and [these](https://www.digikey.in/en/products/base-product/texas-instruments/296/LMV324/6008?utm_adgroup=Supplier_TI_BPN&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=EN_Product_SKU&utm_term=lmv324&productid=&gclid=Cj0KCQjwspKUBhCvARIsAB2IYuuCynYyY8t5gX47YGwI-XX6Z8WaCCP-WEGRCH4OjkBHT3rDTv-utWkaAtxJEALw_wcB) are the available options. I need help because I am not an electronics engineer and can't make the fine distinction between all the types. The sensor is supposed to work on a constant current of 100uA, and some of these amplifiers have operational currents of 40uA, 80uA, 160uA, 410uA. I can't decide.

Comment: Since all the chips you link to seem to be LMV324 made by TI, you should open up that datasheet so see the differences. There has got to be a chapter where they explain what the letters mean when you order parts. Sometimes the difference is package type (through hole, surface mount, wide, narrow), rated temperature range and other usage conditions (commercial, industrial, military grade, space grade), and how they are packaged (tape reel, tray).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, on the current: I think you’re confusing the supply current with **output current**.

The figures you are quoting that are in the uA are either the quiescent (supply) current the op amp will use while powered up.

This is not relevant to the constant current circuit in the sensor data sheet.  What matters there is the op amp’s maximum output current.  And all of them can output at least 40mA, which is 400 times more than what you need, so no worries there.  Any of them will work just fine.

And the reason any of them will work just fine is that on both the Mouser and Digi-Key listings, they’re all the same part.  They all have the same part number, which is LMV324. (which itself is just a low power variant of the LM324).

This part contains 4 operational amplifiers so a single chip should be able to replicate the application circuit in Omron’s data sheet.

The different parts you see are all the same chip, the only differences are, in order of significance, the package/footprint the chip is encapsulated in, the working temperature range, the finish used on the leads (NOPB signifying a lead-free finish), and finally things like if the chips are packaged on a reel or in a tube - something important if you plan on feeding these into a pick and place machine for mass production.

Realistically, you don’t really have to care about any of this stuff if you aren’t already filtering for it.  The only thing to worry about in your case I think is the package.  Most of the parts are SOIC-14, which is the largest surface mount dual-in-line package seen.  It is very popular and widely used, and there are breakout boards available for such chips widely available.

A few of the parts listed are TSSOP, which is some what smaller than SOIC and can be harder to work with if you plan to solder this by hand.  However, it is still doable and breakout boards for these style chips are likewise widely available.  It depends on if small size is important to you or not.

You can see which is which by looking in the package column on either site.

SOIC looks like this:

[image]

And TSSOP like this:

[image]

And here are breakout boards for each side by side so you can get an idea of the relative sizes both to a 0.100” header and each other:

[image]

Comment: Cripes. Not much more can be said about the question. Nice!

Comment: Ohk, thanks very much. I didn't know NOPB meant lead free (I would prefer that). So basically since I have designed my board for SOIC placement, I can use any SOIC? That operation current doesn't matter to the sensor which should work at 100uA?

Comment: @tiktok Correct.  The figure that matters is the output current.  Operation current is just the current the op amp will consume for itself, not the current it is capable of driving (like if used in a constant current application).  So I would just pick the cheapest NOPB part that is a soic and that should work perfectly.

Comment: @metacollin Budd, you've made my day. This thing was consuming me for weeks. Absolutely relieved. Thanks very much again.

Comment: No problem :).  This stuff can be pretty intimidating, especially with so many choices.  You’ll probably encounter multiple variations of most parts, but just remember that it’s the first part that matters, and the data sheet for that part should have a table of all the different variations and what they mean somewhere.

Comment: @metacollin would you cite references for those images you've used please. Mainly because that's the rules of the site, but also they are particularly nice and useful images that I may want to use in one of my answers, and I want to know how to cite them.